# CouchDB Merging Revisions (conflict)

Tags: merge, couchdb, conflict, revision

So I'm causing a conflict on purpose with the example of this site: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html (Working with Conflicts).

Now there are two revisions and CouchDB decides with its own algorithm which revision to use but i would like to keep both revisions and merge them.

As an example: i got Phonenumber: 111  and Name: Jules on **database A** and Phonenumber: 222 and Name: Jules on **database B**.
Is it possible to create a new document which keeps all information from the old and the new revision?
Or a new field like "NewPhonenumber: 222" and the other fields Phonenumber: 111 and Name: Jules ?

I just want to keep both revisions no matter how.

I tried to write a View function but i just don't know how to grab the data from the conflicting database.

```
function(doc) { 
if(doc._conflicts)
emit(doc._id, doc);
emit(doc._id, {oldNumber: doc.phonenumber, newNumber: doc.phonenumber, name: doc.name});
}
```

How can I replace "oldNumber: doc.phonenumber" with the number from the old revision?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be worth you having a look at: https://github.com/glynnbird/deconflict

Answer (score 0):

The property `doc._conflicts` contains one or more conflicted revisions of the doc - you have to iterate over the list and grab the value you want.

If you do this in the view your conflict resolving  will never be stored. You have to send the resolved version of the doc as new revision to CouchDB.

You can request the doc with its conflicts by using the query param `?conflicts=true` (more in the [CouchDB documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/common.html)) and store your decision as new revision.